# Trouble Installing In-House Python Package via pip on Windows from Local Server

Tags: python, linux, windows, pip, conda

***I'm trying to install a custom, in-house Python package from a local server onto Windows machines in my LAN. I've followed the steps below, but I'm encountering an issue.***

***Summarized steps:***

- Created a custom package with a setup.py file.
- Generated a wheel file for the package.
- Hosted the wheel file on a local server.
- Modified pip.ini for the client machine.
- Attempted package installation, but encountered errors.

***Detailed steps:***

- Created a setup.py following this form:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Define package metadata
name = 'sptools'
version = '0.1'
author = 'author'
author_email = 'email'
description = 'description'
url = 'url'

# Define package dependencies
install_requires = [
    'requests==2.31.0',
    'seaborn==0.13.0',
    'torch==2.0.0',
    'tqdm==4.65.0',
    'utils==1.0.1',
    'visualize==0.5.1'
]

# Define packages to include (you can use find_packages())
packages = find_packages()

# Define classifiers for your package
classifiers = [
    'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: Internal',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
]

# Define the setup configuration
setup(
    name=name,
    version=version,
    author=author,
    author_email=author_email,
    description=description,
    url=url,
    install_requires=install_requires,
    packages=packages,
    classifiers=classifiers,
)
```

- Created a .whl for my files, that if installed locally works as expected. The wheel file's name is `sptools-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`
- moved the wheel onto a server, under `~/packages/sptools-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`
- host the files with `python -m http.server`, and indeed, the file can be manually downloaded with
  `wget http://[server_IP:port]/sptools-0.1-py3-none-any.whl`
- Configured pip on the Client computer, (Windows OS) by modifying pip.ini. This is necessary, as I understand it, for pip to know to not only look withing the pypi.org repositories, but also the local one:

```
[global]
no-cache-dir = true
index-url = http://[ip:port]/
trusted-host = [ip]

[install]
trusted-host = pypi.org pypi.python.org pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
```

- Lastly, I have tried to install the package on the client machine, using both:

```
pip install sptools
# or 
pip install --trusted-host [ip] sptools
```

***Error Messages:***

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sptools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sptools
```

while on the Server I get:

```
[client-ip] - - [11/Oct/2023 17:56:38] code 404, message File not found
[client-ip] - - [11/Oct/2023 17:56:38] "GET /sptools/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[client-ip] - - [11/Oct/2023 17:56:39] code 404, message File not found
[client-ip] - - [11/Oct/2023 17:56:39] "GET /pip/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

***More details:***

- I would like to further state that I have tried inside and outside a conda environment
- I have tripple checked the names to be exactly the same.
- I have tested with a public wheel (requests package) and the behaviour is the same
- I have succesfully installed this why using wget + pip install .whl
- I have tested with `pip config list` to make sure the config that is used is the one that I modified

***I suspect this is an issue with the pip.ini configuration. Can anyone provide advice on how to resolve this issue? Your help is greatly appreciated.***

Comment: Looks like the directory structure of your repository isn't quite right. See [Hosting your own simple repository](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/hosting-your-own-index/#hosting-your-own-simple-repository) and [Simple repository API](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/simple-repository-api/#simple-repository-api). You need to put your wheel files inside a directory with the normalized name of the distribution.

Comment: Side note: Writing `setup.py` files is outdated. You may want to consider switching to `setuptools` current `pyproject.toml` interface, or migrating to a different modern build system. There are several to choose from from the makers of setuptools (hatch, flit), plus great third party ones (poetry)

Comment: Amazing, thank you for all the info !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your in-house repository needs to follow the [Simple Repository API](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/simple-repository-api/#simple-repository-api).

In particular, that means that your wheel files need to be placed in directories named after the [normalized name](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/name-normalization/#name-normalization) of their distributions.

Move `sptools-0.1-py3-none-any.whl` to a directory named `sptools`:

```
<http server root>
└── sptools
    └── sptools-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Make sure that you can retrieve the wheel file with

```bash
$ wget http://[server_IP:port]/sptools/sptools-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

See also [Hosting your own simple repository](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/hosting-your-own-index/#hosting-your-own-simple-repository) from the Python Packaging docs.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the issue, now it works. Thank you! 
Also, I will try to use devpi better, thanks for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't directly address the issue but if you have the repository stored in a git repository, pip has the ability to pip install from one.

See fifth example [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples).